# using vis.js from query result

Tags: javascript, laravel-5.3, vis.js, vis.js-network

I'm using vis.js to show a binary tree. I have all the information on the database and following the docs i tried to replicate it to my needs without results.

The documentation that I used is:

> ```
> <style type="text/css">
>     #mynetwork {
>         width: 600px;
>         height: 400px;
>         border: 1px solid lightgray;
>     }
> </style> </head> <body> <div id="mynetwork"></div>
> ```
>
> // create an array with nodes
>       var nodes = new vis.DataSet([
>           {id: 1, label: 'Node 1'},
>           {id: 2, label: 'Node 2'},
>           {id: 3, label: 'Node 3'},
>           {id: 4, label: 'Node 4'},
>           {id: 5, label: 'Node 5'}
>       ]);
>
> ```
> // create an array with edges
> var edges = new vis.DataSet([
>     {from: 1, to: 3},
>     {from: 1, to: 2},
>     {from: 2, to: 4},
>     {from: 2, to: 5}
> ]);
>
> // create a network
> var container = document.getElementById('mynetwork');
>
> // provide the data in the vis format
> var data = {
>     nodes: nodes,
>     edges: edges
> };
> var options = {};
>
> // initialize your network!
> var network = new vis.Network(container, data, options); </script> </body> </html>
> ```

The abode work just fine, but when i change that it looks like this:

> aqui va la grafica
>
> $.ajax({            headers: {'X-CSRF-TOKEN':
>   $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')},
>               url: "obtenerNodos",
>               data: { id: '1' },
>               method: 'post',
>               success: function (data) {
>                   console.log(data);/////////////////////////////////////////
>
> ```
>             //console.log(data[0]);
>             //var res = JSON.parse(data);
>
>             var res = data.split('"*"');
>
>             var nd = res[0];
>             var gd = res[1];
>
>             //console.log(nd);///////////////////////////////////////
>             console.log(nd);
>             var nodes = new vis.DataSet(nd);
>             var edges = new vis.DataSet(gd);
>
>             // create a network
>           var container = document.getElementById('mynetwork');
>
>           // provide the data in the vis format
>           var data = {
>               nodes: nodes,
>               edges: edges
>           };
>
>           console.log(nodes);///////////////////////////////////////
>           //console.log(nd);
>
>           var options = {
>               nodes:{
>                   borderWidth: 1,
>                   borderWidthSelected: 2,
>                   brokenImage:'http://binario.com/admin/img/profile1.jpg',            
>                   color: {
>                     border: '#2B7CE9',
>                     background: '#97C2FC'
>                     },
>
>                   font: {
>                     color: '#343434',
>                     size: 14, // px
>                     face: 'arial',
>                     background: 'none',
>                     strokeWidth: 0, // px
>                     strokeColor: '#ffffff',
>                     align: 'center',
>                     multi: false,
>                     vadjust: 0,
>                     bold: {
>                       color: '#343434',
>                       size: 14, // px
>                       face: 'arial',
>                       vadjust: 0,
>                       mod: 'bold'
>                     },
>                     ital: {
>                       color: '#343434',
>                       size: 14, // px
>                       face: 'arial',
>                       vadjust: 0,
>                       mod: 'italic',
>                     },
>                     boldital: {
>                       color: '#343434',
>                       size: 14, // px
>                       face: 'arial',
>                       vadjust: 0,
>                       mod: 'bold italic'
>                     },
>                     mono: {
>                       color: '#343434',
>                       size: 15, // px
>                       face: 'courier new',
>                       vadjust: 2,
>                       mod: ''
>                     },
>                   },            
>                   heightConstraint: false,
>                   hidden: false,            
>                   image: 'http://binario.com/admin/img/profile1.jpg',
>                   level: undefined,
>                   shape: 'circularImage',
>
>                   size: 25,
>                   //title: undefined,
>                   //value: undefined,
>                   widthConstraint: false
>                 },
>
>               edges:{
>                   arrows: {
>                     to:     {enabled: true, scaleFactor:1, type:'arrow'},
>                     middle: {enabled: true, scaleFactor:1, type:'arrow'},
>                     from:   {enabled: true, scaleFactor:1, type:'arrow'}
>                   },
>                   color: {
>                     color:'#161616',
>                     highlight:'#848484',
>                     hover: '#848484',
>                     inherit: 'from',
>                     opacity:1.0
>                   }
>               },
>
>               layout: {
>                   randomSeed: undefined,
>                   improvedLayout:true,
>                   hierarchical: {
>                       enabled:true,
>                       levelSeparation: 150,
>                       nodeSpacing: 100,
>                       treeSpacing: 200,
>                       blockShifting: true,
>                       edgeMinimization: false,
>                       parentCentralization: true,
>                       direction: 'UD',        // UD, DU, LR, RL
>                       sortMethod: 'directed'   // hubsize, directed
>                   }
>               }
>           };
>
>           // initialize your network!
>           var network = new vis.Network(container, data, options);
>             //do something
>
>         },error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
>                 console.log(xhr.status+" ,"+" "+ajaxOptions+", "+thrownError);
>             }
>
> });
> ```
>
> ---

When the console show me the "console.log(data);", i get this:

> {id: 1, label: 'Carlos Corrales'},{id: 2, label: 'Carlos
>   Jaramillo'},{id: 3, label: 'Carlos Jaramillo Corrales'}"*"{from: 1,
>   to: 2},{from: 1, to: 3}

When the console show me the "console.log(nd);", i get this:

> {id: 1, label: 'Carlos Corrales'},{id: 2, label: 'Carlos
>   Jaramillo'},{id: 3, label: 'Carlos Jaramillo Corrales'}

That i just fine, but when the console show me "console.log(nodes);", i get this:

> n {_options: "{id: 1, label: 'Carlos Corrales'},{id: 2, label:
>   '…llo'},{id: 3, label: 'Carlos Jaramillo Corrales'}", _data: {…},
>   length: 0, _fieldId: "id", _type: {…}, …} length : 0
>   _data :
>   **proto** : constructor : ƒ Object() hasOwnProperty : ƒ hasOwnProperty() isPrototypeOf : ƒ isPrototypeOf()
>   propertyIsEnumerable : ƒ propertyIsEnumerable() toLocaleString : ƒ
>   toLocaleString() toString : ƒ toString() valueOf : ƒ valueOf()
>   **defineGetter** : ƒ **defineGetter**()
>   **defineSetter** : ƒ **defineSetter**()
>   **lookupGetter** : ƒ **lookupGetter**()
>   **lookupSetter** : ƒ **lookupSetter**() get **proto** : ƒ **proto**() set **proto** : ƒ **proto**()
>   _fieldId : "id"
>   _options : "{id: 1, label: 'Carlos Corrales'},{id: 2, label: 'Carlos Jaramillo'},{id: 3, label: 'Carlos Jaramillo Corrales'}"
>   _subscribers : {add: Array(1), update: Array(1), remove: Array(1)}
>   _type :
>   **proto** : Object
>   **proto** : Object

So it's says tha the length of the nodes array is 0.

The code that i use to get the data is:

> public function obtenerNodos(Request $request){
>
> ```
>     $id = $request->id;
>
>     $nodos = "";
>     $edges = "";
>
>     $senal = 0;
>
>     //while ($senal == 0)
>     //{
>         $res = panelController::getNodos($id);
>         $valores = explode("**",$res);
>
>         $nodos .= $valores[0];
>
>         if($valores[1] != "-99"){
>             $edges .= $valores[2];
>             $nodos .= ",".$valores[3];
>         }
>
>         if($valores[4] != "-99"){
>             $edges .= ",".$valores[5];
>             $nodos .= ",".$valores[6];
>         }
>
>         //$senal = 1;
>     //}
>
>     $nodos .= "";
>     $edges .= "";
>
>     //return $edges;
>
>     $regreso = $nodos.'"*"'.$edges;
>
>
>     return $regreso;
> }
> ```

So the problem is the data is not getting into the node and enges arrays, in that way i can not get the graph.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this to figure out the problem, because i think you have problem with your format of *nd* and *gd* that you put to Dataset

Your goal is to get an array of objects like:

```
Array [Object, Object, ... etc]
 where Object {id: 0, label: "node"} - for example
```

You can get this format directly when you execute query and put the results in a variable

```
$data = $connection->createCommand("YOUR_SQL")->queryAll();
```

convert it to JSON and then you can for example hide it in a html tag like:

```
<p class="no_display" id="myId"><?= json_encode($data) ?></p>
```

put the data to JS variable like:

```
var network_nodes = JSON.parse(document.getElementById("myId").innerText);
```

now just assign it to DataSet:

```
var nodes = new vis.DataSet(network_nodes);
```

and you got it right.

This always works for me, hope it helped!